# How to loop through two object keys in typescript?

Tags: typescript, syntax-error

I made a Vector class but I have some problem with the syntax.

This is my code:

```
export class Vector {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  add(v: Vector) {
    var x: number, y: number;

    for (var component in this) {
      component == "x"
        ? (x = this[component] + v[component])
        : (y = this[component] + v[component]);
    }

    return new Vector(x, y);
  }
}
```

Here is the syntax problem I have:

[image]

As you see "x" and "y" in line "return new Vector(x,y)" say "Variable 'x' is used before being assigned"... And for the "v[component]" says "Type 'Extract<keyof this, string>' cannot be used to index type 'Vector'."

I don't know what I have done wrong, the code works but I want to write it correctly.

Comment: Why not the [simple and straightforward way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYwDYEMDOOUBqYaC8KA3gFAo0oQBcKAdgK4C2ARmHANzW0BPRq07c+-GmhhMcCOCxLwAFBBQBeFAAYANCgHqtASgoTaNBAAsAljgB0qjRD5mzlm7f0aBz2gF9KplgAJkFKAG6MRIpwxlQutHBgCCxwTMxgAO6ExKRwSqbx5tZ2qgDUKGH22gWFbnb65ZUC1YUohj40-v5AA)? The loop just complicates things without providing any benefit as far as I can see... Dynamic loops over property keys are problematic when you're trying to use a static type system (TypeScript). They're *possible*, but problematic.

Comment: Side note: Please don't use the conditional operator where an `if` statement is the logical choice. There's literally no reason to do so. `if (component === "x") { /*x = ...*/ } else { /*y = ...*/ }`.

Comment: That was my first idea but I want to complicate things to learn how to use it. I came from use JavaScript so I wanna do things more complicated xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally this is the way I would do it.

```
  add(v: Vector): vector {
    const res = new Vector();

    Object.keys(this).forEach(component => {
      res[component] = this[component] + v[component];
    });

    return res;
  }
```

I threw together a quick sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/competent-lichterman-5weip?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This produces a variation of the same compiler error in the question: [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DVgJtOAbwCg44QAuOAOwFcBbAI2CgG5S4BPKupl9jggjU0MKLTwEAFCDgBeOAAYANF3lKAlEQ5kYACwCWaAHSyFIdmV2GTndZ0twAvsQ4oAJu6kA3KjklQGn64+FDaVojConBQwJgK1MAA7tgh0FIaAhEA8owAViHGANbAnGhS+kYaxgBm0ACiKAh6UkL0kInU8HIAfOERMXEA2m0dwF0AuuqVaCMQ7cLjMFMA1HDecwudy45kTpmuEbEwtFDUg2iOLi5AA)

Answer (score 2):

[@T.J. Crowder has commented some sound advice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966365/how-to-loop-through-two-object-keys-in-typescript#comment123679993_69966365) However, if you are intent on using a loop in your method, you'll need to narrow the key type for the compiler:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoBUCeADhogDy6IC8i4A1mHAO5gB8AFAG7IA2IGAXDTD0mYAJSC0mHKkRdeJGLIoBvAL4AoDRgAehODkQRuUxADUM0A4hUbEiHYLAgAtgCNsAbjuJ8T1x5Y3j4QCKhQWCBWWIhsOlSIAAwANL4JiWI2PvZQABZKAHTx1Dre9jn5qAX4CfhliJo+yAAmzbEcghbREuaWUNa25UZhUHKWCWAYjL3RbGLBQ8DWbKFg4Yi0GDUwSByWmYNDiAD0xzSoOwDmKIguyM48KOjYsAj82eVQRCQA0gkA5Dp-ogAD6If74f71IZ7CAAbU2NTQiB+AF0EnklAitk8UeiANRybFI2RohZHU6IawgC5ga73J7SV5IUCQZmIJYxTGyVChYjvI4nM5SF4EYikQHAsEQ-7sRHzD72Smw4no6jc1WIQkcVXQhpaIZYDBQEBYXaWeqaTRAA)

You can do it manually:

```ts
add (v: Vector): Vector {
  const vec = new Vector();

  for (const key in vec) {
    type K = 'x' | 'y';
    vec[key as K] = this[key as K] + v[key as K];
  }

  return vec;
}
```

Or by using an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for the remainder of the scope:

```ts
function assertType <T = unknown>(value: unknown): asserts value is T {}
```

```ts
add (v: Vector): Vector {
  const vec = new Vector();

  for (const key in vec) {
    assertType<'x' | 'y'>(key);
    vec[key] = this[key] + v[key];
  }

  return vec;
}
```

Comment: I'd also be curious to know OP's reason for not just doing `new Vector(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y)`

Comment: There's no reason to repeat `x` and `y`, just use `type K = keyof Vector;`. (I'd also use `Key` or `VectorKey` for clarity, rather than `K`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, that still produces a compiler error: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEGGZm)

Comment: @jsejcksn - Doh! Of course. (I've had my coffee now. :-) ) But I'd solve that by excluding function property keys rather than repeating `x` and `y`. Also, I'd strongly suggest not using empty assertion functions (in dev; they can be empty in prod after testing, e.g. via `assert` or similar). So something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZbbPm).